# Parse xml feed with jquery and look for variable

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to parse through an XML that has the format:

```
 <companies>
   <company>
     <code>ABC</code>
     <url_title>ABC website</url_title>
     <url>http://www.example.com</url>
   </company>   
   <company>
     <code>DEF</code>
     <url_title>DEF website</url_title>
     <url>http://www.example.com</url>
   </company>   
   <company>
     <code>GHI</code>
     <url_title>GHI website</url_title>
     <url>http://www.example.com</url>
   </company>  
   <company>
     <code>ABC</code>
     <url_title>ABC website version 2</url_title>
     <url>http://www.example.com/version-2</url>
   </company>  
 </companies>
```

I am using jQuery parse to get this file (list.xml) it then sets a variable from the page (var currentCode) sets this to uppercase. I then need to see if this variable exists within list.xml and if so, I want to return the respective  and  and add these values to an  tag within my html.

I am stuck with the following function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "list.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseXml
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("company").each(function () {
        var currentCode = $('#code').html().toUpperCase();
        var url = $(this).find("url").text();
        var url_title = $(this).find("url_title").text(); 
        // code to filter through XML file and only return url and url_title if companies equals currentCode
        $("#myDiv").append("<a href=" + url + ">" + url_title + "</a>");
    });
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the response as a parameter? Assuming the response is valid XML

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "list.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
      parseXml(data)
    }
});
```

Here's a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zixita/1/edit?js,console) of a working example (uses newer ajax callbacks)

Comment: I am not sure that solves the problem, I still cannot see if my variable exists in the XML file.

Comment: I apologize - I misread the question. Why not just do an `if` string comparison?